# clicking on child element, calls parents on:click function in svelte

Tags: javascript, onclick, svelte-3

when a child element is clicked the event attached to the parent gets triggered in svelte. I tried the same approach in simple CSS and HTML it worked perfectly whereas in svelte the parent action gets triggered. I have a REPL code below which simulates my scenario where clicking inside child prints "hi" in the console.

```
<script>
let name = 'world';
</script>
<div style="padding:50px; border:solid;height:200px; z-index:1" on:click={() => {console.log('hi')}}>
    <div style="border:solid;height:200px; z-index:999">
        <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to use `self` modifier
[svelte event event-modifiers](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-modifiers)

```js
<div style="padding:50px; border:solid;height:200px; z-index:1" on:click|self={() => {console.log('hi')}}>...</div>
```

Comment: see also `stopPropagation`